# what techniques might improve vslam performance?

Tags: ros, vslam-system, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have implemented the vslam_system and am in the process of testing it with some of my own data sets.  I was wondering if there are any plans to improve the computational speed in the future.  At the moment the computational performance is very acceptable in the beginning of a run and typically taking about 12.51 ms between frames, but eventually (after approximately 100 frames), it slows down to upwards of 890 ms between frames.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9607/what-techniques-might-improve-vslam-performance?/) by [jcurtis_swri](https://answers.ros.org/users/367/jcurtis_swri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-12**:
Would you mind re-titling this as a question? I'm hoping to set a trend to make browsing and answering questions easier. Perhaps something like "Is there a way to improve VSLAM performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How is the memory footprint? A while ago I found a significant memory leak (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4753); it might be related.

---

Originally posted by [dimatura](https://answers.ros.org/users/528/dimatura/) with karma: 46 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1